# Python global var in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables, python-multiprocessing

For the following code, I declare 'GlobalCount' that is intended to be the global variable.
Then I start the process() method with multiprocessing, that increments GlobalCount each second. If I set a breakpoint there, the value is incremented ok.
Then, in parallel, I am requesting 'GETSTATUS', who should return the value of GlobalCount. However, it is always 0! What I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Updated code:

```
import multiprocessing
import socket
import time

from multiprocessing import Value

#globals
GlobalCount = Value('i', 0)  # 'i' stands for integer

def main():

    server_ip = "127.0.0.1"
    server_port = 2222

    # Create a UDP socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_address = (server_ip, server_port)
    server_socket.bind(server_address)

    response = ""

    print("UDP server is listening on {}:{}".format(*server_address))

    while True:
        
        # Receive data from the client
        data, client_address = server_socket.recvfrom(256)

        if data:

            data_str = data.decode('utf-8') 
            arrayParams = data_str.split(';')

            if arrayParams[0] == "PROCESS":

                server_socket.sendto(response.encode(), client_address)

                # Start the process in parallel
                training_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process)
                training_process.start()

            elif arrayParams[0] == "GETSTATUS":
                current_value = GlobalCount.value
                response = str(current_value) #here GlobalCount is always 0
                server_socket.sendto(response.encode(), client_address)

            else:
                print("")



def process():

    for i in range(100):
        
        with GlobalCount.get_lock():  # Ensure thread-safety when updating the value
            GlobalCount.value += 1
        time.sleep(1)


#Execute at start
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Multithreading would probably be better suited to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only share synchronised objects through inheritance. Here's an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Pool

N = 100

def ipp(v):
    global gCount
    gCount = v

def process(_):
    with gCount.get_lock():
        gCount.value += 1

def main():
    gCount = Value('Q', 0) # unsigned long long
    with Pool(initializer=ipp, initargs=(gCount,)) as pool:
        pool.map(process, range(100))
    print(gCount.value == N)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

Comment: I turned into multithreading as you suggested... And with the same approach of global var, it is working as expected! thanks

Answer (score 1):

In python, multiprocessing don't create a *thread* but a *process* with it's own memory space.

You can try something like this using *multiprocessing.Value* :

```
from multiprocessing import Value

GlobalCount = Value('i', 0)  # 'i' stands for integer

# In your process function:
def process():
    for i in range(100):
        with GlobalCount.get_lock():  # Ensure thread-safety when updating the value
            GlobalCount.value += 1
        time.sleep(1)

# When reading the value:
current_value = GlobalCount.value
```

Edit after comment :

```
import multiprocessing
import socket
import time

def main():
    # Use multiprocessing.Value to create a shared variable
    GlobalCount = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)

    server_ip = "127.0.0.1"
    server_port = 2222
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_address = (server_ip, server_port)
    server_socket.bind(server_address)
    print("UDP server is listening on {}:{}".format(*server_address))

    while True:
        data, client_address = server_socket.recvfrom(256)
        if data:
            data_str = data.decode('utf-8') 
            arrayParams = data_str.split(';')
            if arrayParams[0] == "PROCESS":
                response = "Started processing"
                server_socket.sendto(response.encode(), client_address)
                training_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(GlobalCount,))
                training_process.start()
            elif arrayParams[0] == "GETSTATUS":
                response = str(GlobalCount.value)
                server_socket.sendto(response.encode(), client_address)

def process(GlobalCount):
    for i in range(100):
        # Modify the shared variable using GlobalCount.value
        GlobalCount.value += 1
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Should I keep setting 'global GlobalCount' into the method?

Comment: Nope, instead of global GlobalCount -> multiprocessing.Value

Comment: Same problem. GlobalCount is always 0 when requesting the value. I updated the code based on your suggestion

Comment: Synchronized' object is not iterable... multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(GlobalCount))

Comment: same approach than chatgpt... that I was also trying at first. Not working

Comment: GPT propose an approach with multiprocessing.Queue for me.. Wich I think is not suitable.

Could you provide more results of your adapted code ?

Comment: Thank you, multithreading instead of multiprocessing solved the issue